# Trying to calculate the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{-1}\choose n}z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to calculate the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1}{n}z^n$.

Here is what I have so far:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1}{n}z^n &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1-j)\bigg)z^n \\&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{n!}\cdot (-1)^n\cdot\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1)\bigg)z^n \\&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{n!}\cdot n! \cdot (-1)^n\bigg)z^n \\&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^n
\end{align*}
Now I am kind of stuck. Trying to apply the Cauchy product I just end up with $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\cdot z^k\cdot z^{n-k}\bigg)=\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^n\bigg) \cdot \bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n\bigg)$$
leading to some sort of infinite regress. Anybody got a clue for me?

Comment: Forgive me for being ignorant, but is not $(-1)!=\frac{1}{0}$? I'm also sure you know this, but can't you use $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-z)^n=\frac{1}{1+z}$?

Comment: What's $1/(1+z)$?

Comment: From the Generalized Binomial Theorem, $$(x+y)^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{a}{n}x^{a-n}y^n$$Now, let $x=1$, $y=z$, and $a=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far is correct. What's missing in the last step is to apply the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) formula
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^n = a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots = \frac{a}{1-r},$$
which is valid for $|r|<1$. 
Have you seen this formula before?

(If you are interested in a nice generalization of this identity, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) out.)

Comment: But what if, as in this case, $a=(-1)^n$?

Comment: are you sure that's the right choice of $a$? in the formula $a$ is the _first_ term, and $r$ is the _ratio_ between successive terms

Comment: Oh, I see. So we get $\frac{1}{1-((-1)\cdot z)}=\frac{1}{1+z}$, is that right?

Comment: yes! that's correct. to see the general pattern though, it also helps to think of the answer as $(1+z)^{-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\binom{-1}{n}=(-1)^{n}\frac{n!}{n!}=(-1)^n.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\binom{-1}{n}z^{n}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-z)^n=\frac{1}{1+z};\quad (|z|<1)
$$
by the geometric series.